# openCV Preview window freezes when the script is waiting for outside input

Tags: python, opencv

I have a python script utilizing cv2 to display a portion of a given picture/stream. It works great when controlling the the displayed portion via keyboard presses:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("Testpicture.jpg")
rows, cols, _ = img.shape
print("Rows", rows)
print("Cols", cols)
y=0
x=0
h=400
w=600
#crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
#cv2.imshow('Image', crop)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

    
while (1):
    crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('Image', crop)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 115: #s
        print (key)
    
    newY = y + 20
    if newY < (rows-h):
        y = newY
    crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
elif key == 27: #ESC
    break
elif key == 119: #w
    print (key)
    newY = y - 20
    if newY > 0:
        y = newY
    crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
elif key == 97: #a
    print (key)
    newX = x - 20
    if newX > 0:
        x = newX
    crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
elif key == 100: #d
    print (key)
    newX = x + 20
    if newX < (cols-w):
        x = newX
    crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
else:
    print (key)
```

But I'm trying to control the movement via a node.js applet on the same machine. I've played around with a local file that gets written to by the node.js and read by the python script, but that didn't work just like the following example:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import numpy as np


MAX_LENGTH = 4096

def handle(clientsocket):
  while 1:
    buf = clientsocket.recv(MAX_LENGTH)
    if buf == '': return #client terminated connection
    message =  (buf.decode("utf-8") )
    if message == "down": #s
        
        newY = y + 20
        if newY < (rows-h):
            y = newY
        crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    elif message == "end": #ESC
        break
    elif message == "up": #w

        newY = y - 20
        if newY > 0:
            y = newY
        crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    elif message == "left": #a

        newX = x - 20
        if newX > 0:
            x = newX
        crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    elif message == "right": #d

        newX = x + 20
        if newX < (cols-w):
            x = newX
        crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]



serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

PORT = 10000
HOST = '127.0.0.1'

serversocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
serversocket.listen(10)

img = cv2.imread("Testpicture.jpg")
rows, cols, _ = img.shape
print("Rows", rows)
print("Cols", cols)
y=0
x=0
h=400
w=600


while 1:
    crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('Image', crop)
    #accept connections from outside
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()

    ct = Thread(target=handle, args=(clientsocket,))
    ct.start()
```

I'm not very experienced yet, I guess the problem lies within the two `while(1)` loops, here's the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2w3B.png).

Any idea how to fix this or a better approach to control the script programmatically?
As far as I can tell, running a subshell in node.js wouldn't work in this case, since I need the preview window to be visible (and showing a livestream from a webcam) at all times.

Comment: I see `cv2.imshow`, so where's the `cv2.waitKey`? Without it the GUI won't work, the documentation is quite clear about it. | Just have it wait 1 millisecond, so it has a chance to pump the events.

Comment: However the whole loop mixing UI rendering and even processing, with accepting connections, and also each iteration creating a new thread... that's a much bigger mess. Split things up, have a thread that listens for and accepts connections, and then spawns per-connection threads (if you need to have more than one connection, that is... seems unnecessary for what you're doing). Add a synchronized queue to deliver the commands to the main thread that handles the UI.

Comment: Well, talk about not seeing the forest because of all the trees. Thank you!